# Regex not working in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a *Powershell* file `myfile.ps1`:

```
function Do-It
{
    $items = # A command that returns a collection of strings like:
             # Element 12657 - <Description trext>
             # Element 12656 - <Description trext>
             # Element 12655 - <Description trext>
             # ...

    $pattern = 'Element\s(\d*).*';
    foreach ($item in $items) {
        $res = $item -match $pattern;
        $len = $matches.Length;
        $id = $matches[0];
        Write-Output "$len $id";
    }
}
```

The problem is that my output is:

```
1 Element 12657 - <Description trext>
1 Element 12656 - <Description trext>
1 Element 12655 - <Description trext>
...
```

So no match found. However, if I execute this from `cmd`, then I get results.

What am I doing wrong? Need to escape something? Thanks

Comment: `$matches` is `Hashtable`. `Hashtable` does not have `Length` property. For PowerShell V3+, auto property `Length` will return 1 regardless of content of hash table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look and see what it's doing manually:

```
PS U:\> $item = 'Element 12657 - <Description trext>'
PS U:\> $pattern = 'Element\s(\d*).*'
PS U:\> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              12657
0                              Element 12657 - <Description trext>
```

I would try `$id = $matches[1];`.

Comment: Damn, stupid me... I knew the first or the last was the whole, did not look at numbers in the first column and thought it was a 0. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first match of a regular expression is the entire matched string. So, the match that you want is `$matches[1]`. I believe that `$Matches.Length` returns 1 because it is a list of matches with one single match that contains two groups.